# How to round a double to an int using Banker's Rounding in C

Tags: c, algorithm, rounding

I want to write a function to round a double to an int using Banker's Rounding method (round half to even: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), like:

```
int RoundToInt(double x);
```

How can I do that?

**Update**:

The best I can get is this:

```
int RoundToInt(double x)
{
  int s = (int)x;
  double t = fabs(x - s);

  if ((t < 0.5) || (t == 0.5 && s % 2 == 0))
  {
    return s;
  }
  else
  {
    if (x < 0)
    {
      return s - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return s + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

But this is slow and I'm not even sure if it is accurate.

Is there some quick and accurate way to do this.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: @AdamCasey I need this to be solved, and I failed to solve it, so I came he for some help. Or is my question a really silly one?

Comment: Your need and question is not the problem.  Check the link in my comment; you need to show that you a. Put some effort into researching the problem, b. Attempted to write some code yourself, and c. Attempted to debug your code when it has failed

Comment: @AdamCasey I've done my research and I don't think it's helpful. My code is slow and clumsy, I don't know if it is accurate. This is the best I can do.

Comment: That is what a good question looks like now.  I changed my down vote to an up vote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard `lrint` function; in the default rounding mode, it gives exactly the result you want.

Comment: You sure about that? The man page you linked to doesn't mention what happens when the number is exactly between two integers.

Comment: `lrint` obeys the current rounding mode. The default rounding mode is round-to-nearest, also known as round-to-even, or "bankers" rounding.

Comment: I'm using VC++, it doesn't support `lrint`.

Comment: Does it support `rint`? Using `rint` then casting the result to an integer type (or letting it get implicitly converted by an assignment) should work just as well.

Comment: No, it seems that VC++ only support C90 standard.

Comment: This won't banker's round in any realistic situation. The value you pass to `lrint` will already by rounded because it's in a non-exact (floating point) format. Double-rounding is not banker's rounding.

Comment: You're making additional assumptions.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to rely on something that depends on global state. For example, a library might modify the rounding mode, and an old version of Visual Studio was even known to [temporarily modify it when casting to an int](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-floating-point-to-integer-conversions). If that happens in another thread while this code is running, you could get the wrong result.

Comment: @ArthurTacca: Rounding mode is thread-local state, not global.

Answer (score 1):

```
double decimal = x % 1;
if(decimal < 0.5) return (int)x;
if(decimal > 0.5) return (int)x + 1;
return (int)x + ((int)x % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work correctly. You're allowing accumulated error to change your rounding method, and that is not correct. For example `round(5.0 / 2.0)` *must* use the rounding rule for `2.5`. But if your round function sees that as `2.4999999993` (due to rounding in the division), it will use the wrong rule.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Why do you claim it should work this way? I see no basis for making that judgement.

Comment: That is the definition of banker's rounding. "A perfect half is rounded to the nearest even number." If you don't ensure you round 7/2 to 4, it ain't banker's rounding.

Comment: I'm talking about your claim that it should treat 2.4999999993 as 2.5; I see no basis for that. Moreover your claim that 5.0/2.0 could be 2.4999999993 is nonsense; 5.0/2.0 is always exact.

Comment: That's why I said *if*. I'm trying to show with a simple example what the problem is. If other functions round so that you don't see an exact half, the banker's rounding function will do the wrong thing. The same thing could happen if a bunch of fractions were added together.

Comment: The point of banker's rounding is to ensure that if the exact result would have been an even half, the result is rounded to the nearest integer. This function won't do that because it acts on whether the rounded result is an even half, not the exact result. (How you fix it depends on context and usually involves using some delta in the check for .5 -- this will fail to banker's round in many cases where it should do so.)

Comment: Double-rounding is not a solution to the problem; for every case it "fixes", there are just as many cases where it causes rounding in the wrong direction. The moral of the story is that floating point is never a valid format for money.

Comment: @R..: I agree. But the function above is just wrong. It won't actually banker's round. It tests whether the *rounded* result is an even half, which is simply broken. You have to banker's round the *unrounded* result -- double rounding is not banker's rounding. (The fix is usually to use a delta in the test for .5, and correctly computing this delta is non-trivial.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you're saying that the %1 operation will cause precision problems?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I don't see any justification for calling it a rounded result. It's just a number. If it is the result of an inexact computation, then yes, it's rounded, but your proposal to "fix" it does not work.

Comment: @bdares: There is no `%` operator for floating point. `fmod` is the equivalent, and it's an exact operation.

Comment: @R..: Whatever you want to call it, it's not an exact representation. So comparing it exactly to 0.5 will not determine accurately if the exact result would have been less than or greater than 0.5 -- this is what is required for banker's rounding.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Any floating point number has an exact value, and comparing it in this manner is completely valid. What's not valid is double-rounding. If the value is already the result of rounding (which it may or may not be; OP provided no such information to us) then attempting to perform "banker's rounding" on it is a second rounding step (double rounding) and thus invalid. There's no way around this.